# iOS Swift: Mapbox route calculation not working, "Value of type 'Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>' has no member 'first'"

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

So I was following a tutorial I found on YT "Build an iOS App: (2/4) Calculating Route with Mapbox Navigation SDK" and encountered a problem while trying to follow on my own.

Somehow xCode throws me multiple errors while creating the calculateRoute function, especially in Directions.shared.calculate(..). Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox
import MapboxNavigation
import MapboxDirections
import MapboxCoreNavigation

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate{

//is the View that shows the map
var mapView: NavigationMapView!

//Saves the route
var directionsRoute: Route?

//creates the button
var navigateButton: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    //view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.21, blue: 0.24, alpha: 1.00)
    mapView = NavigationMapView(frame: view.bounds)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(mapView)
    
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
    
    addButton()
    
}

func addButton(){
    navigateButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.width/2) - 100, y: view.frame.height - 200, width: 200, height: 50))
    navigateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigateButton.setTitle("Route finden", for: .normal)
    navigateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    navigateButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Demibold", size: 18)
    navigateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    navigateButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
    //navigateButton.layer.shadowColor = C
    navigateButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    navigateButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    navigateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navigateButtonWasPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(navigateButton)
}

@objc func navigateButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
    
}

func calculateRoute(from originCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destinationCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (Route?, Error?) -> Void ){
    let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: originCoor, coordinateAccuracy: -1, name: "Start")
    let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: destinationCoor, coordinateAccuracy: -1, name: "Finish")
    
    let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination], profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)
    
    _ = Directions.shared.calculate(options, completionHandler: { (wayponts, routes, error) in
        self.directionsRoute = routes?.first //HERE IS THE ERROR
        
        let coordinateBounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: destinationCoor, ne: originCoor)
    })
}
```

}

I have marked the line that causes the issue. xCode tells throws the following errors:

1. Contextual closure type '(Directions.Session, Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>) -> Void' (aka '((options: DirectionsOptions, credentials: DirectionsCredentials), Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>) -> ()') expects 2 arguments, but 3 were used in closure body
   once I remove the third argument (error) from the lign above, two new errors appear:
   2)Value of type 'Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>' has no member 'first'
   3)Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>'

I can't seem to fix it as I am a beginner. I also can't find any documentation about it.
The line of code should set directionsRoute to the first route from the routes that are returned. I followed the tutorial step by step, did I miss something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter – there are only two – is a `Result` type, an enum with associated values. It contains both the `routes` and the `error`

You have to write

```
_ = Directions.shared.calculate(options, completionHandler: { (waypoints, result) in
    switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            guard let route = response.routes?.first else { return }
            self.directionsRoute = route
            let coordinateBounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: destinationCoor, ne: originCoor)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }  
})
```

Comment: This does not seem to fix the issue. The Problem with routes?.first is still there and the last line throws a new error: Type 'Result<RouteResponse, DirectionsError>' has no member 'error'". However, this is fixable by writing .failure instead of .error

Comment: I can't believe it. It works as it should! And I learned something new. Thanks for the fast help

Comment: By the way, there is a documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/ios/directions/api/0.31.0/Classes/Directions.html#/s:16MapboxDirections0B0C22RouteCompletionHandlera